# ls command and size of files in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ls

```
count=0;      #count for counting
IFS='
'
for x in `ls -l $input`;     #for loop using ls command
do 
a=$(ls -ls | awk '{print $6}')   #print[6] is sizes of  file
echo $a

b=`echo $a | awk '{split($0,numbers," "); print numbers[1]}'`
echo $b     
if [ $b -eq 0 ]          # b is only  size of a file
then
count=`expr $count + 1`   #if b is zero , the count will increase one by one
fi
echo $count
done
```

I want to find 0 size files . I do that using find command. The second thing is I want to count number of has 0 size of files using ls command and awk. But It doesn't true code . What is my mistake ?

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: I don't know the other usage. Ls isn't true ? @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: @lurker Even that is not recommended because the number of lines of output is not the number of files if any file names contain a newline.

Comment: @chepner indeed that's true, although it's pretty rare. I'll delete my suggestion.

Comment: I realize it's rare, but I think that suggestions in a public forum should take more care to be correct than code you might use yourself. (You never know under what circumstances someone may try to use your suggestion, and it's better if you can avoid unpleasant surprises due to unstated assumptions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main mistake is that you're [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!

If you want to find (regular) files that are empty, and if you have a version of `find` that supports the `-empty` predicate, use it:

```
find . -type f -empty
```

Note that this will recurse in subfolders too; if you don't want that, use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty
```

(assuming that your `find` also supports `-maxdepth`).

If you only want to count how many empty (regular) files you have:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -printf x | wc -m
```

and if you want to perform both operations at the same time, i.e., print out the name or save them in an array for future use, and count them:

```
empty_files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    empty_files+=( "$f" )
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -print0)
printf 'There are %d empty files:\n' "${#empty_files[@]}"
printf '   %s\n' "${empty_files[@]}"
```

With Bash≥4.4, you could use `mapfile` instead of the `while`-`read` loop:

```
mapfile -t -d '' empty_files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -print0)
printf 'There are %d empty files:\n' "${#empty_files[@]}"
printf '   %s\n' "${empty_files[@]}"
```

---

For a POSIX-compliant way, use `test` with the `-s` option:

```
find . -type f \! -exec test -s {} \; -print
```

and if you don't want to recurse into subdirectories, you'll have to `-prune` them:

```
find . \! -name . -prune -type f \! -exec test -s {} \; -print
```

and if you want to count them:

```
find . \! -name . -prune -type f \! -exec test -s {} \; -exec printf x | wc -m
```

and here, if you want to perform both operations (count them and save them in an array for later use), use the previous `while`-`read` loop (or `mapfile` if you live in the future) with this `find`:

```
find . \! -name . -prune -type f \! -exec test -s {} \; -exec printf '%s\0' {} \;
```

---

Also see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463703/ls-command-and-size-of-files-in-shell-script/33463838#33463838) for a pure shell solution (needs minor tweaking to be POSIX compliant).

---

Regarding your comment

> I want to count and delete [empty files]. How can I do that at the same time?

If you have GNU `find` (or a `find` that supports all the goodies):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty -printf x -delete | wc -m
```

if not,

```
find . \! -name . -prune -type f \! -exec test -s {} \; -printf x -exec rm {} \; | wc -m
```

Make sure that the `-delete` (or `-exec rm {} \;`) predicate is at the end! *do not exchange the order of the predicates!*

Comment: I want to count and delete 0 bytes . How can I do that at the same time ?

Comment: @esrtr see the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 2):

The `-s` test is true if a file has non-zero size. If that test fails for  file, increment your empty-file count.

```
empty_files=0   
for f in "$input"/*; do
    [ -s "$f" ] || : $(( empty_files++ ))
done
```